# Prolog - Find second smallest number in list

Tags: prolog

Uni Homework

Predicate secondSmallest/2 with the signature secondSmallest(List,S2) where S2 is the second lowest valued element in some list of numbers.

I tried to find the smallest, delete it then find the new smallest. But I'm getting an error

`ERROR: is/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated`

```
secondSmallest(List, S2) :- 
   S is min_list(List, S), 
   delete(List, S, NewList), 
   S2 is min_list(NewList, S2).
```

Comment: You're closer than you think. :) Prolog does not "return" values like this. `min_list(List, S)` is all you need, you cannot also have `S is ...` in front of it.

Comment: Perfect it works thank you :)